# Nginx сменить версию php

Tags: php, ubuntu, .htaccess, nginx, сервер

Для корня сайта я установил версию php 7.4 и она корректно работает!
В корневой папке сайта я создал папку и загрузил в него скрипт, который работает на версии php 5.6.
Чтобы установить php 5.6 я использовал команды:

```
apt install php5.6
apt install php5.6-fpm
```

Далее я подумал, что можно применить версию php прямо в папке, создав там файл `.htaccess` и написав в нём:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
```

Но это не помогло. Я думаю, что нужно это делать в конфиге `nginx`, но там только для основного сайта я понимаю как прописать версию. Вот код конфига:

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;


    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            # proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include fastcgi_params;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
           fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
           deny all;
    }
```

}

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но разве нельзя сделать отдельный конфиг файл в `sites-available` с указанием расположения и нужной версией `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;`? или новый `location` в `default` конфиге.

Comment: Спасибо, решил так: прописал новый location для папки